# Change the Z-index between 2 absolute elements ?

Tags: html, css, position

I have a simple html structure (I *can't* change it )

```
 <div class="d1"  >
       <div class="d2" >
             <div class="d3"></div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

The outer div is `position:relative`

The other (inner) 2 divs are `absolute position`.

[image]

However  , I want the `green` to be *under* the `red`

The `red` has a *greater* `z-index` and still it doesn't apply

What am I missing?

**[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/otiniw/1/edit)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `z-index` from the red div and make it negative in the green div:

http://jsbin.com/otiniw/14/edit

Comment: +100. can you please explain what the prob was ? I mean , I think I followed the rules quite right... no ?

Comment: I think this may answer your question: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index

Comment: I read it and couldn't find the line where it says _something_ about the situation where 2 absolute divs are one inside the other.

Comment: @RoyiNamir `Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in back-to-front order:` ... `2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).` #2 is relatively early in the order.